# Fill in groups with max of corresponding values [pandas]

Tags: pandas

I have one column which contains value of an event.

```
[15, 30, 10, 25, 10, 5, 15, 20, 15]
```

The second column defines whether we are in event A or B

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Based on the index of the value in relation to what event it falls under, i want to "fill" the events with corresponding values.

```
[30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20]
```

Since the index of the first 30 value falls under this particular section of event A, we fill that event in with the 30 and so on.

The example is here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [15, 30, 10, 25, 10, 5, 15, 20, 15],
                   'event': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']})

    val event
1  15.0     A
2  30.0     A
3  10.0     A
4  25.0     A
5  10.0     B
6   5.0     B
7  15.0     A
8  20.0     A
9  15.0     A
```

I want my output column to be `[30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `transform` with `shift` and `cumsum`

```
df.groupby(df['event'].shift().ne(df.event).cumsum()).val.transform('max')

0    30
1    30
2    30
3    30
4    10
5    10
6    20
7    20
8    20
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this works. It takes the global max of an event when it should be the local (ie. the last 3 values should be 20)